# BATCH: FOR LOOP with IF ELSE , mysql and directory

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I need some help. I want to get the database name in MySQL to make it as directory name. But my code is not correct . it fails.

```
e.g
DATABASE NAME 
- sample
- sample_test
```

i want to create a directory with the same name as database name.

my code is:

```
@echo off
SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop
cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
SET UserName=root
SET UserPass=root

mysql -u%UserName% -r%UserPass% -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%'" |
FOR /F %%D IN ('C:\Windows\System32\findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"') DO @echo %%D 
IF exist %path%\%%D (echo %%D exist) 
ELSE (mkdir %path%\%%D && echo %%D created)
```

i got this result: i add **pause** command to pause the terminal and the display is

```
sample IF exist C:\Users\neca\Desktop\sample (echo sample exist) 
ELSE  (mkdir C:\Users\neca\Desktop\sample sample created)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

when i test it just like this the output is correct

```
 @echo off
 SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop
 cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
 SET UserName=root

 mysql -uroot -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%'" 
 pause
```

output:

```
 sample
 sample_test
 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It fails how? Any errors?

Comment: i add **pause** command to pause the terminal and the display is **sample IF exist C:\Users\neca\Desktop\sample (echo sample exist) ELSE (mkdir C:\
Users\neca\Desktop\sample
sample created)
Press any key to continue . . .** @GolezTrol

Comment: First, **do not change** the system environment `path` variable not even temporarily; use another variable name, e.g. `SET "pathX=C:\Users\neca\Desktop"` and read again [Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Then you could try `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (``command with apostrophes here``) DO (code snippet)` and note that  _code snippet_ in parentheses could consist of more than one command lines (only one backquote, I can't escape it!)

Comment: Please set `echo ON` and provide _full_ output from that `mysql ..."` command (including echoed one). Alone `mysql ...` without next `|` piped one. Insert `pause` immediately behind it instead. Copy a result from CLI window, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28427395/edit) your question and paste it there.

Comment: when i test it just like this the output is correct

     **@echo off
     SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop
     cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
     SET UserName=root

     mysql -uroot -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%'" 
     pause**


output:

     **sample
     sample_test
     Press any key to continue . . .**
@JosefZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under next circumstances:

```
mysql -uroot -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%sample%'" 
sample
sample_test
Press any key to continue . . .
```

this batch script should work:

```
 @echo off
 pushd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
 SET "pathxxx=C:\Users\neca\Desktop"
 SET "UserName=root"
 for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
        `mysql -uroot -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%'"`
    ) do (
          echo processing "%%G"
          IF exist "%pathxxx%\%%~G" (
              echo %%G exist 
          ) ELSE (
              echo mkdir "%pathxxx%\%%~G"
              echo %%G created
          )
    )
 popd
```

Notes:

- do not change the system environment variable `path`, not even temporarily; use another variable name, here `pathxxx`;
- instead of `chdir` command used `pushd` .. `popd` pair: `popd` will change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the `pushd` command;
- `usebackq` forces alternate quoting style in `for /F` command; essential as your command contains `'` single quotes;
- as a matter of general principle, used `%%~G` with the `~` [argument modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to remove surrounding quotes (`"`) if any;
- `echo mkdir "%pathxxx%\%%~G"` for debugging purposes only (get rid of the `echo` word when debugged.