# BATCH: FOR LOOP with IF ELSE

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I need some help. I want to execute for loop with if-else statement but i got some error.
This is my code

```
mysql -u%UserName% -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" | FOR /F %%D IN ('C:\Windows\System32\findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"') DO (IF EXIST %pathx%\%%D (echo test) ELSE (echo fail))
```

The output is

```
< was unexpected at this time
```

Comment: does any of your strings contain "<" . LIke `%pathx%` ?

Comment: Please show a sample output from the `mysql` command

Comment: it does not contain. **SET path=C:\Users\neca\Desktop** thats it sir. @npocmaka

Comment: this is just the output sir.
**< was unexpected at this time** @Magoo

Comment: You are piping the output of the `mysql` command **mysql -u%UserName% -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';"** into a `for/f` command. I've asked for a sample output of that `mysql` command.

Comment: the sample output is
**sample
  sample_test**
@Magoo

Comment: from that output i want that to be the name of the directory to be created via if-else sir. @Magoo

Comment: [Possibly duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28427395/3439404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error report is incorrect. The output you are receiving is

```
( was unexpected at this time
```

You can't validly pipe output into a `for` statement. Change your code to

```
FOR /F %%D IN ('mysql -u%UserName% -N -B -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%%sample%%';" ^| C:\Windows\System32\findstr /V "information_schema performance_schema"') DO (IF EXIST %pathx%\%%D (echo test) ELSE (echo fail))
```